# Align two div tags in one line

Tags: html

Please see this page

http://www.radioclever.stream/

As you can see it outputs:

> Trenutno: 
>  Ellie Goulding - Something In The Way You Move 
>   Slušaoci: 
>  1

But i want

> Trenutno: Ellie Goulding - Something In The Way You Move 
>   Slušaoci: 1

I tried anything i found on stackoverflow and nothing helped.
This is source code

```
        <div class="onAir" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px">Trenutno:</div><div class="onAir" id="track-title" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px">Changing song ...</div>
        <div class="onAir" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px">Slušaoci:</div><div class="onAir" id="listeners" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;padding:0 10px 20px 10px;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the difference of the two texts!~

Comment: `display: inline;` Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i have tried that

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy You can see the difference now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here your code with a container, to avoid repeating the style in each `<div>` i put it in the `<div>` container's style

```html
<div style=";background:#0277bd;color:#fff;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;">
  <div class="onAir" style="display: inline-block;">Trenutno:</div>
  <div class="onAir" id="track-title" style="display: inline-block;">Changing song ...</div><br>
  <div class="onAir" style="display: inline-block">Slušaoci:</div>
  <div class="onAir" id="listeners" style="display: inline-block">1</div>
</div>
```

and here if you want it in the center

```html
<div style=";background:#0277bd;color:#fff;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;text-align: center;">
  <div class="onAir" style="display: inline-block;">Trenutno:</div>
  <div class="onAir" id="track-title" style="display: inline-block;">Changing song ...</div><br>
  <div class="onAir" style="display: inline-block">Slušaoci:</div>
  <div class="onAir" id="listeners" style="display: inline-block">1</div>
</div>
```

and if you want it all in one line , remove `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use either `float:left`.
here how it should be:

```html
<div class="onAir" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px; float:left;">Trenutno:</div>
<div class="onAir" id="track-title" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px; float:left;">Changing song ...</div>
<div class="onAir" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;">Slušaoci:</div>
<div class="onAir" id="listeners" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;padding:0 10px 20px 10px;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;"></div>
```

or `display: inline-block`
and this how it should look like:

```html
<div class="onAir" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;display: inline-block;">Trenutno:</div>
<div class="onAir" id="track-title" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px;display: inline-block;">Changing song ...</div>
<div class="onAir" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px">Slušaoci:</div>
<div class="onAir" id="listeners" style="color:#fff;background:#0277bd;padding:0 10px 20px 10px;font-family:Montserrat;font-size:14px"></div>
```

Comment: When i Put that "I got a blank space baby"

Comment: i mean white background around text

Comment: so add a container with blue background instead of making eatch one a background